# How to connect Airflow to AWS S3 without secret keys?

Tags: airflow

I want to connect Airflow to S3 and be able to take data from a bucket. However the only tutorial on how to do it uses AWS Secret Access Key. I don't want to use them. So I would like to ask If Airflow supports any other way to connect to S3 ?

Comment: The short answer: No.

Answer (score 1):

If you run Airflow in EC2 machine, or in ECS containers, you can benefit from EC2 instance profile. In this way, you don't need to setup any credentials, and any boto3 request will use the authentication permissions provided by the Instance Profile. From Airflow side you can just use the default aws_default and only set up the region in the extra section.